# TINYMCE Length : asp.net mvc

Tags: sql, tinymce

this is my code to check the length of tinymce contant

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            tinymce.init({
                selector: 'textarea',

                setup: function (ed) {
                    ed.on('keyup', function (e) {
                        var count = CountCharacters();
                        document.getElementById("character_count").innerHTML = "Characters: " + count;
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        function CountCharacters() {
            var body = tinymce.get("Body").getBody();
            var content = tinymce.trim(body.innerText || body.textContent);
            return content.length;
        };
        function ValidateCharacterLength() {
            var max = 4000;
            var count = CountCharacters();
            if (count > max) {
                alert("Maximum " + max + " characters allowed.")
                return false;
            }
            return;
        }
    </script>
```

it return the length without  (html tags) so the max size is 4000 but if i make it bold , Chang color 
it be more than 4000 so can't store it in SQL
how i can determine the length with HTML tags ?

e.g : this is the length with bold [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbFai.png)

but in SQL it the lenght :33

i change code to as bellow

```
@model TinyEditorWithMVCApp.Models.Post


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddPost";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Add new Post</h2>


<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>TintMCE App</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            tinymce.init({
                selector: 'textarea',

                setup: function (ed) {
                    ed.on('keyup', function (e) {
                        var count = CountCharacters();
                        document.getElementById("character_count").innerHTML = "Characters: " + count;
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        function CountCharacters() {
    var content = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent({format: 'raw'});
     return content.length;
};
        function ValidateCharacterLength() {
            var max = 4000;
            var count = CountCharacters();
            if (count > max) {
                alert("Maximum " + max + " characters allowed.")
                return false;
            }
            return;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("AddPost", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AuthorName)
            </div>

            <div>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Body)
            </div>

            <div id="character_count">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Save Post" onclick="return ValidateCharacterLength();" />


            </div>

        }
    </div>
    <div id="character_count">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i guess that get incorrect result

it give me that the character 8 even it's (test) must be 4 and i don't add any HTML tags [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eecRU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#getcontent) you can read raw content

```
// Get the HTML contents of the currently active editor
console.debug(tinymce.activeEditor.getContent());

// Get the raw contents of the currently active editor
tinymce.activeEditor.getContent({format: 'raw'});

// Get content of a specific editor:
tinymce.get('content id').getContent()
```

in your case I would try to change

```
function CountCharacters() {
    var content = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent({format: 'raw'});
     return content.length;
};
```

Examples from JSFiddle:

- empty editor - tinyMCE puts there by default `<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>` and gives length as `30`
- `example` as input then html behind it is `<p>example</p>` and length is `14`
- bold `example` as input then html is

  **example**

  and length is `31`

Working sample on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mybrave/rkbqzdyo/).

Comment: i use console.debug(tinymce.activeEditor.getContent());
 instead of             var body = tinymce.get("Body").getBody();

it's not work !

Comment: of course you need to change your code to the suggestion :) see update

Comment: please check , i edit the Q and try change code as you said

Comment: what I need to check? please test the change and confirm it works or not. I cannot do it for you:) if you still have problem then try to provide e.g. JSFiddle to demonstrate the issue. Also please learn how to use browser developer tools for local JavaScript debugging.

Comment: No i mean that i change the code as you say but give incorrect result it start count from 8 instead of 0 and when i change the color this tags not counted

Comment: I think it works well. it gives you length of underlying html - see the examples in my answer.

Comment: If i want to add table how i can fix it ? Since that the default  tinymce not have it

Comment: How to add to timymce toolbar? just enable the toolbar. Ideal is to start from documentation - https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/table/. if you have trouble to update your code then create new question on StackOverflow

Comment: Try using plugins